# DevExpress control with different field name and JavaScript control name

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

When you render a DevExpress MVC control, you define the `Name` field, which is used both for the model binding and the name of the JavaScript object that is created to access the control.

Is there a way to define a different name for the JavaScript object?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var textBoxSettings = new TextBoxSettings
{
    Name = "ModelName.FieldName",       
};
writer.Write(devExpress.TextBox(textBoxSettings).GetHtml());
```

Answer (score 0):

use the settings.Properties.ClientInstanceName

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I don't have the code any more so I can't verify this.  Can anyone else confirm if this is working for them?